# Kendo Grid saveChanges() doesn't work

Tags: kendo-grid

I'm trying to set status field of the row with a custom command button. Grid data source transport is defined like this:

```
transport: {
  read: {
    url: "/agent/AgentList",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: addAntiForgeryToken
  },
  update: {
    url: "/agent/UpdateAgent",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: addAntiForgeryToken
  }
},
```

Custom command is defined as following:

```
{
  command: [
    {
      name: "accept",
      visible: function(dataItem) {
        return dataItem.StatusId === 1;
      },
      text: "@T("Ralfeus.Agent.Accept")",
      click: function(e) {setOfferResponse(this, e, 2);}
    }
  ]
}
```

The function actually setting the field is defined as following:

```
function setOfferResponse(grid, sender, response) {
  sender.preventDefault();
  var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(sender.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
  dataItem.StatusId = response;
  grid.editRow($(sender.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
  grid.saveChanges();
}
```

I expected saveChanges() call to trigger update method of datasource transport. However it neither causes any requests to server nor reports errors.

I also tried to replace grid.saveChanges() with grid.dataSource.sync() (by the way - what's the difference?) as was suggested [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-how-to-save-changes-from-dropdownlist-editor#Y1A0-7XD6kmuCMf1mkeqkw) but result was same: no HTTP request, no errors.

Comment: @-> can you see any error on console ?

Comment: No. There are no errors reported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, found the reason. Programmatic changing of dataItem fields doesn't make them dirty. So I had to make it dirty:

```
dataItem.dirty = true;
grid.saveChanges();
```

Then it worked